# 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapAzureSignalR'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-signalr

I am new to Azure Signal Services, am trying to get my application hooked to Azure Signal R services. I am doing a proof of concept, to check the feasibility to use in my application.

**Code**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<NotifyHub>("notify");
        });

        app.MapAzureSignalR(this.GetType().FullName); ---Error code
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I am using .NET Core 2.2 and also added the reference to Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet version 1.0.0-preview1-10317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a reference to **`Microsoft.Azure.SignalR`** and MapAzureSignalR was available in intellisense and it compiled successfuly.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.SignalR -Version 1.0.6
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the **`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Http`** (https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-ci-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Http) package now.